# Does an anonymous class that implements a private abstract static class hold a reference to its enclosing class, when created in a non-static context?

Tags: java

I read in Effective Java, 3rd Edition that anonymous classes created in non-static contexts contain invisible references to their enclosing class. Is the same true for an anonymous class that is implementing an inner static class, but created in a non-static function?

For example:

```
class Concept {
    public Response func() {
        return new Inner {
            @Override
            protected Object bar() {
                return new Object;
            }
        }.invoke();
    }

    private abstract static Inner {
        protected Response invoke() {
            return Response.status(SC_OK).entity(bar).build();
        }

        protected abstract Object Response bar();
    }
}
```

Does the anonymous class created in the func() method contain a reference to its enclosing class, Concept?

Comment: Non-static methods *are* a type of non-static context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [JLS §15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5):

> An anonymous class is always an inner class (§8.1.3); it is never static (§8.1.1, §8.5.1).

Note that there are no exceptions in the JLS for the case that the anonymous class is extending a `static` class.

Therefore, it should have a reference to an instance of its enclosing class.

---

I simplified your example to turn it into a legal self-contained Java class, compiled it and looked at the bytecodes for the anonymous class using `javap -c`.  The constructor code *does* take a reference to the enclosing class and it *does* save it in a hidden field (`this$0`).

```
class Concept {
    public Inner func() {
        return new Inner() {
            @Override
            protected Object bar() {
                return new Object();
            }
        };
    }

    private abstract static class Inner {
        protected abstract Object bar();
    }
}
```

---

```
javap -c 'Concept$1.class'
Compiled from "Concept.java"
class Concept$1 extends Concept$Inner {
  final Concept this$0;

  Concept$1(Concept);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: putfield      #1                  // Field this$0:LConcept;
       5: aload_0
       6: invokespecial #2                  // Method Concept$Inner."<init>":()V
       9: return

  protected java.lang.Object bar();
    Code:
       0: new           #3                  // class java/lang/Object
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       7: areturn
}
```